# Is the induced map of a connected subspace on $0$th homology always injective?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was asked whether or not the following is true:

> Let $Y$ be a topological space, $X \subset Y$ a subspace, and $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$ the inclusion map. Then the induced map on homology $f_{*}:H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ is always injective.

This is of course false. Take $S^1$ embedded in $S^2$, par exemple. Then $H_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$ while $H_1(S^2) = 0$.

But this got me thinking: What if we restrict ourselves to the $0$th homology?

If $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion map, is the induced map $H_0(X) \to H_0(Y)$ on $0$th homology always injective?

Here a counterexample would be taking two distinct points $x,y \in S^1$. Then $H_0(\{x,y\}) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ while $H_0(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$.

But if we restrict ourselves even more:

If $X$ is a *connected* subspace of $Y$, and $f: X \hookrightarrow Y$ is the inclusion map, is the induced map $H_0(X) \to H_0(Y)$ on $0$th homology always injective?

I have been unable to find a counterexample, but am also unsure as to how one would prove this.

All help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since the $0$th homology counts the connected components, then yes this is true.  It’s even easier to see in cohomology since the $0$th cohomology corresponds to locally constant functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not true, take the topologists sine curve embedded in $\mathbb R^2$ for example. It is connected but not path connected, it has two path components so its $0-th$ homology is $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ and of course the $0-th$ homology of $\mathbb R^2$ is $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 6):

No, you need *path-connectedness*. Consider the inclusion of $X$ in $Y=\Bbb R^2$
where $X$ is a connected but not path-connected space, for instance the closure
of the "topologist's sine curve".